# How to find the expected CPU run time?

Tags: floating-point, runtime, cpu

My question is "How to find the the expected CPU run time for this problem"… (I'm not looking for an answer, but just want to know how to solve it.)

A program that runs 10 billion (10×109) instructions executed (trace),

where 40% are floating point (FP) instructions.

And  will run on computer M with a 400 MHz clock CPU,

where all instructions take 2 clock cycles

except FP instructions take 8 clock cycles. Ignore all non-CPU overhead.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  If it is, our honor code holds that you should add the tag [homework].  This question also seems "off topic" because it's not a question about software development.

Answer (score 2):

Take the number of calculations. Find the number of FP (40% of total) and non-FP calculations (whatever's left or in this case 60%). Multiply each by their clock cycles and add up the clock cycles. To find time you need to multiply clock cycles times the amount of time it takes to do one clock (HINT: use 400MHz to do this).